# I cannot get desired result from my code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatable

I need to create dataTable from mysql database with google visualisation api. So i do this this:

```
try {

  $rez = $db->prepare("SELECT naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND prvi=1 AND user_id=:user_id");
  $rez->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':user_id' => $user_id));

  $kol = $rez->fetchAll();
  $rows = array();
  $rows1 = array();
  $table = array();
  $table = array();

  $rows[] = array('label' => 'Datum', 'type' => 'string');

  foreach ($kol as $r) {
    $rows[] = array('label' => (string) $r['naziv'], 'type' => 'string');
  }

  $table['cols'] = $rows;
  // convert data into JSON format
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT datum FROM track_aktivnosti 
                                WHERE id_akt = :id_akt 
                                AND user_id=:user_id 
                                GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum");

  $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':user_id' => $user_id));
  $dates = $result->fetchAll();
  $final_result = array();

  $rows1 = array();
  foreach ($dates as $date) {

    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT vrednost, naziv 
                                    FROM track_aktivnosti 
                                    WHERE id_akt = :id_akt 
                                       AND datum = :datum  
                                       AND user_id= :user_id");

    $result->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'],
        ':datum' => $date['datum'],
        ':user_id' => $user_id));
    $m = array(array('v' => $date['datum']));
    foreach ($result as $r) {
      $m[] = array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']);
    }
    $rows1[] = array('c' => $m);

    $table['rows'] = $rows1;
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode($table);
```

So all is fine but this code change row values... as you can see from mysql database and in front end dataTable: so DataTable is: (for id_akt = 82)
[image]

and mysql database is:

[image]

so as you can see in datatable i get for `fdfdfd` value 56 instead 76 and similar... How I can solve this?

UPDATE WITH JS CODE:

```
function drawTroskovnik() {
  var cssClassNames = {
    'headerRow': 'zaglavlje',
    'tableRow': 'red',
    'oddTableRow': 'red',
    'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background large-font',
    'hoverTableRow': 'prekoreda',
    'headerCell': 'gold-border',
    'tableCell': 'cell',
    'rowNumberCell': 'underline-blue-font'
  };

  // Create and populate the data table.
  var JSONObject = $.ajax({
    url: 'getTroskovnik.php', // make this url point to the data file
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id_akt: ajdi},
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
  }).responseText;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONObject, 0.5);

  for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    for (var x = 1, maxcols = data.getNumberOfColumns(); x < maxcols; x++) {
      data.setValue(y, x, '<input vr="' + data.getValue(y, 0) + '" kol="' + data.getColumnLabel(x) + '" class="form-control costRedovi" value="' + data.getValue(y, x) + '">');
    }
  }
  for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    data.setValue(y, 0, '<input class="span2 form-control" id="pocetak1" size="16" type="text" value="' + data.getValue(y, 0) + '" readonly>');
  }

  data.addColumn('string', '');
  for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    var mc = data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1;
    data.setValue(y, mc, '<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete this day data"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" ></i></div>');
  }

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('tpltroskovnik'));
  new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    $(".costRedovi").focusout(function() {
      var vrednost = $(this).val();
      var datum = $(this).attr('vr');
      var tabela = $(this).attr('kol');
      console.log(datum + " " + tabela + " " + vrednost);
      $.ajax({
        url: "updateCost.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: {ajdi: ajdi, datum: datum, tabela: tabela, vrednost: vrednost}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
      });
    });
  });

  table.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true, cssClassNames: {
      'headerRow': 'zaglavlje',
      'tableRow': 'red',
      'oddTableRow': 'red',
      'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background large-font',
      'hoverTableRow': 'prekoreda',
      'headerCell': 'gold-border',
      'tableCell': 'cell',
      'rowNumberCell': 'underline-blue-font'}
  });
};
```

Comment: Check the resulting array and then check the code logic

Comment: code logic is ok, but i get different result into frontend...

Comment: Can you check if your json looks like this? `{"cols":[{"label":"Datum","type":"string"},{"label":"fdfdfd","type":"string"},{"label":"IMT 510-td","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2013-04-01"},{"v":1},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-04-16"},{"v":76},{"v":56}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-04-22"},{"v":4},{"v":3}]}]}`. I tried recreating everything, got that json data and dumped this data into Google's DataTable, it showed what I believe is the correct table http://imgur.com/kJUQawv . Maybe you should post your javascript code?

Comment: I update question with JS code

Comment: Please rename the title with a descriptive one such as "Create dataTable from mysql database with google visualisation api" It will better attract those who can help.

Comment: @gmaestro your javascript has extra trailing commas after the `success` key and `type: 'POST',`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PHP code you provided there's no correlation between the column names and the row values. Therefore what values fall in which columns depends on the order the data is pulled from the database, which may be based on performance or insertion order, and can vary from one query to another. In order to have a predictable order, you need to specify in the query the order you want it pulled. The two queries that need to be aligned are: the one that pulls the names, and the one that pulls the values.

.

Lacking predictable ORDER:

```
$rez = $db->prepare("SELECT naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND prvi=1 AND user_id=:user_id");

...

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT vrednost, naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND datum = :datum AND user_id= :user_id");
```

.

Add `ORDER BY naziv` at the tail end of each of these to sort the results into a predictable alignment, which then gets properly loaded in your associative array, followed by the JSON object.

Here's a tweaked version of your code, cleaning up a few other non-critical issues:

```
<?php

try {

    $res = $db->prepare('SELECT naziv FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND user_id = :user_id AND prvi = 1 ORDER BY naziv');
    $res->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':user_id' => $user_id));
    $kol = $res->fetchAll();

    $rows = array();
    $table = array();

    $rows[] = array('label' => 'Datum', 'type' => 'string');

    foreach ($kol as $r) {
        $rows[] = array('label' => (string) $r['naziv'], 'type' => 'string');
    }

    $table['cols'] =  $rows;

    $res = $db->prepare('SELECT datum FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND user_id = :user_id GROUP BY datum ORDER BY datum');
    $res->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':user_id' => $user_id));
    $dates = $res->fetchAll();

    $rows = array();

    foreach($dates as $date){

       $res = $db->prepare('SELECT vrednost FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE id_akt = :id_akt AND user_id = :user_id AND datum = :datum  ORDER BY naziv');
       $res->execute(array(':id_akt' => $_POST['id_akt'], ':user_id' => $user_id, ':datum' => $date['datum']));
       $vals = $res->fetchAll();

       $m = array( array( 'v' => $date['datum'] ) );

       foreach($vals as $r) {
           $m[] = array('v' => (int) $r['vrednost']);
       }
       $rows[] =  array('c' => $m);

       $table['rows'] = $rows;
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($table);

?>
```

Comment: Thats right anser but why you use $_GET, I use $_POST I think its better to use POST ?

Comment: I temporarily changed it to GET for easier troubleshooting (then I can load the page by itself with necessary variables in the URL), and forgot to change it back to POST when posting it here. I fixed it.

Comment: Is that vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: No, check this out: https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

"The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this."

Sweet!